# How does "Passing in Parameters" work?

Tags: function, methods

With about every language that I learn more about, I always hear about, "passing in parameters".

Could you explain it like, "for a dummy" style? :)

An example of what I am talking about below..

```
function myfunction(para1, para2) {
    //run code here...
}
```

So, where does para1, and para2 come from?

Why do they exist?

What is their use?

Etc..

I have looked around trying to figure out what they're and where they come from, but something isn't clicking.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)

Comment: I've read that before, what I am saying is that doesn't really make sense either. I'm more of an analogy person, or comparison of equivalence even.

Comment: They're passed in by the code that calls the function. Presumably, they're used within the function to provide values that the function needs to operate. This really is extremely basic. :-( We're not really a *pre-tutorial* question site. If you've learned anything at all about a single language, you should understand an extremely basic concept.

Comment: Yes I agree, it's very basic, I do have experience with multiple languages, and I have actually wrote code using parameters (or tweaked templates more or less), but I never truly understood the overall concept until now. @user3437460 had a great post that helped out, and now I get it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3437460 Thanks, it did help! I ended up needing that extra two rep points, after posting this question. Haha. Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: @BenDains Glad to help. Do note that for each question, you can only accept 1 solution. That means if more than 1 solution was given in a question, you can only accept one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer your question, I think you should know what a function (or a method) is in the first place.

A function is a block of code where it will only execute when you call(invoke) it, otherwise it just sit there doing nothing. There are tonnes of benefits using functions:

- Modularization of codes
- Makes your codes easier to read and debug
- Ease the maintenance of your codes
- Implement once, use n times
- and more..

Now, imagine you have a function call `getMax()`. It is a very general function where you it will return you the larger value when you give (pass) values to it.

Since it shall receive 2 values for its calculation, the function will accept 2 arguments (mentioned as parameter in your question).

So now `getMax()` shall look like `getMax(int val1, int val2)`.

So with the 2 given values:

```
if val1 > val2, then 
    return val1 
else return val2
```

From here we see that the 2 `args` (arguments) can be any 2 integer values provided by you.

---

You can also imagine a function as a machine. For example, having an ice-cream making machine. You need to provide the ingredients (such as cream and milk) for ice-cream making.

In this case, the ice-cream machine is your function, the arguments in the parameter list are the ingredients needed (cream, milk), and the return value is the ice-cream:

```
function IceCream iceCreamMaker(Cream cream, Milk milk){
    return iceCream;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That actually makes sense when you say it like that. Basically using arguments aka parameters, you're running the function against those? Say 3 people were in a contest to guess the right number out of 10. If the function logic says the answer is 5, and each person picked a different number, you could pass the numbers in and run them against the function to see who won?

Comment: @BenDains Yes, your usage of a function for number guessing is alright. I have further updated my solution to give you an analogy of an ice-cream maker. As you understand the basics of a function, you will learn that we try to create decoupled functions, but that is another story.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @user3437460's answer:

So if you have `function getMax(int val1, int val2)`, which looks like:

```
function getMax(val1, val2) {
    if (val1 > val2) {
        return val1;
    } else {
        return val2;
    }
}
```

Then you want to invoke/call it, for example, when a user clicks on a button.

Now, when you call it, instead of using "`getMax()`", you'll put your two variables in the parenthesis, **in the same order as the parameters in the original `getMax()` function**: `getMax(4, 7)`.

Same order, yes, that means now `4` will be used as `val1`, and `7` as `val2`. After the function is done, it will **return** `7` since the first condition wasn't met (`if (val1 > val2)`, or actually `if (4 > 7)`).

They're used to somehow have dynamic variables in functions.